# How to print to the return value of a function, using format modifiers, in C?

Tags: c, c-strings, string-literals

Don't know if this is possible. I've been searching for it but nothing comes up.

I'd like to have a function that *merges* multiple values and returns them **as a string literal** (so no malloc and subsequent free). This could be achieved by printing to the return value (if that makes sense and is possible), or maybe using fprintf with a literal as destination, instead of say `stdout`, and then that literal could be returned.

The parameters of the function below are just an example, there could be other types such as long, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *format_and_return_literal(const char *s, int n, char c)
{
        int m = 7;

        //(1):  Possible to fprintf to return value of function?
        //fprintf(<func-return-literal>, "hello %s: %d %d %c", s, m, n, c);
        //return <func-return-literal>;

        // or

        //(2):  Possible to return string literal made of above parameters?
        //return "hello %s: %d %d %c", s, m, n, c)
}

int main()
{
        printf("%s\n", format_and_return_literal("foo", 33, 'M'));
        return 0;
}
```

---

**Update:** Thank you all. Perhaps the terminology I used wasn't the most correct, but I achieved what I wanted following @Davislor's suggestion of using a static buffer. I'm aware of snprintf but thank you anyway, @PeterJ.

```
char *format_and_return_literal(const char *s, int n, char c)
{
        static char buf[1024];
        int m = 7;

        snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "hello %s: %d %d %c", s, m, n, c);

        return buf;
}
```

Comment: String literals are fixed at compile-time, what you ask is impossible.

Comment: "returns them as a string literal (so no malloc and subsequent free)" - that's not how it works. You can't retroactively preallocate these strings. You need to allocate them dynamically, and you need to free them dynamically.

Comment: Your options include: memory allocation; using preallocated fixed-sized buffers; or also passing into the function enough information for the function to output the result to the device

Comment: "Stack buffers" are also possible but risky, in case the input happens to cause a stack overflow

Comment: He says "literal" but probably he thinks "string"

Comment: @PeterJ: I think literal would be correct. I'd like to send stuff into the function, parse it as I see fit, then return the result as a string literal which doesn't need to be freed. Davislor suggests the use of a static buffer, so that would not be a literal but should do what I want (essentially not having to worry about freeing memory).

Comment: Not literal. Literal is something fixed for example "5&_&_3&_43". You can't change it as it is an UB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `snprintf` to a fixed-size, `static` buffer and return that.  Subsequent calls would then overwrite the previous return value.  Alternatively, pass in the destination buffer, owned by the caller. as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Abstracting from logic of such a solution you have version of the printf which "prints" to the given buffer it is called ***sprintf*** and another ***snprintf*** which is a bit more safe